# The algebra of matrix

Tags: functional-analysis

How to prove the following statement:
The spectral radius is not a seminorm on the algebra of $M_2$ of $2\times 2$matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider matrices
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$